# get values from array and add into one string

Tags: c#, .net

Object `Book` has `Author` which has property `Name` of type `string`.

I want to iterate trough all Authors and add it's Name string to the one string (not array) separated by comma, so this string should be at the as

```
string authorNames = "Author One, Author two, Author three";
```

---

```
string authorNames = string.Empty;
foreach(string item in book.Authors)
{
    string fetch = item.Name;
    ??
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `string.Join` function with LINQ

```
string authorNames = string.Join(", ", book.Authors.Select(a => a.Name));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using LinQ, there are plenty of ways to merge multiple string into one string.

```
book.Authors.Select(x => x.Name).Aggregate((x, y) => x + ", " + y);
```

To anwsers James' comment

```
[TestMethod]
public void JoinStringsViaAggregate()
{
    var mystrings = new[] {"Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma"};
    var result = mystrings.Aggregate((x, y) => x + ", " + y);

    Assert.AreEqual("Alpha, Beta, Gamma", result);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this would work? Don't you need a seed/accumulator function to use aggregate?  What are the types of x and y here, one of the must be an accumulated value (i.e. a string in this case) which wouldn't have a Name property?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
string authors = String.Join(", ", book.Authors.Select(a => a.Name));
```

Comment: +1. strategic downvote?
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is the way to go in C#, but for explanatory purposes here is how you could code it explicitly:

```
string authorNames = string.Empty;
for(int i = 0; i < book.Authors.Count(); i++)
{
    if(i > 0)
        authorNames += ", ";
    authorNames += book.Authors[i].Name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also loop through them all, and append them to authorNames and add a comma in the end, and when it's done simply trim of the last comma.

```
string authorNames = string.Empty;
foreach(string author in book.Authors)
{
    string authorNames += author.Name + ", ";
}
authorNames.TrimEnd(',');
```